# How to resolve this error in solidity "The constructor should be payable if you send value."?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

In this solidity code the `finalizeRequest()` is giving a run-time error.
Here is the error :

```
Campaign.finalizeRequest(uint256) 0x692...77b3a

transact to Campaign.finalizeRequest errored: VM error: revert.
revert  The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value.  Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

Here is the code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Campaign {
    struct Request {
        string description;
        uint value;
        address  recipient;
        bool complete;
        uint approvalCount;
        mapping (address => bool) approvals;
    }

    address public manager;
    uint public minimumContribution;
    // address[] public approvers;
    mapping (address => bool) public approvers;
    Request[] public requests;
    uint public approversCount;


    function Campaign(uint minimum) public {
        manager=msg.sender;
        minimumContribution=minimum;
    }

    function contribute() public payable {
        require(msg.value>minimumContribution);
        // approvers.push(msg.sender);
        approvers[msg.sender]=true;
        approversCount++;
    }

    function createRequest(string description,uint value,address  recipient) public restricted {
        // require (approvers[msg.sender]);    
        Request memory newRequest=Request({description:description,value:value,recipient:recipient,complete:false,approvalCount:0});
        requests.push(newRequest);

    }

    function approveRequest(uint index) public {
        Request storage request=requests[index];

        require(approvers[msg.sender]);
        require(!request.approvals[msg.sender]);
        request.approvals[msg.sender]=true;
        request.approvalCount++;
    } 

    function finalizeRequest(uint index) public restricted {
        Request storage request = requests[index];

        require(request.approvalCount>=(approversCount/2));
        require(!request.complete);
        request.recipient.transfer(request.value);
        request.complete=true;

    } 

    modifier restricted() {
        require (msg.sender == manager);
        _;
    }
}
```

As far as I could debug, when I comment out `request.recipient.transfer(request.value);` in the `finalizeRequest()` function no runtime error is thrown. So error seems to be in this line of code.

Comment: @VishwaRatna yeah its still there I added payable both to the function and construction but the error is still there

Comment: thanks @VishwaRatna after some debugging and your advice the code is successful ,if you want you may undelete your answer and I mark it as accepted to close this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i see your `finalizeRequest()` function consists transfer of ether as defined `request.recipient.transfer(request.value);` so you need to make your  `finalizeRequest()` as `payable`.

replace `finalizeRequest()` with:

```
function finalizeRequest(uint index) public restricted payable {
    Request storage request = requests[index];
    require(request.approvalCount>=(approversCount/2));
    require(!request.complete);
    request.recipient.transfer(request.value);
    request.complete=true;
}
```

> **Thumb Rule:** Whenever you are *sending* or *receiving* ether in any function, mark it as `payable`.

Reason why you need `payable` keyword is well explained [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/20874/payable-function-in-solidity).

Comment: yeah its still there I added payable both to the function and construction but the error is still there

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/79209/57126 ,this guy tells there is any other error. Do you think the same?

Comment: `1st` I don't see any point here making constructor as `payable`. `2nd` if you don't have enough funds in contract then the operation will be reversed as coming in error also. The error you see over remix browser are really misleading as they are generic ones.